# Is there a point in the moon where the gravity is earth like?

Tags: gravity, space-colonization, moons

Supposing, out of boredom, we were to settle on the moon.
I read that at certain depths on earth, the gravity is stronger than on the surface, so presumably the same is true to Luna.
If so, then is there a point, at some depth beneath the lunar surface, where the gravity is more earth-like than up top?

Comment: "at certain depths on earth, the gravity is stronger than on the surface" - the exact opposite is true unfortunately for your story. It decreases as you go down, then at the Earth's centre everything balances out and there's the bottom of the local potential well.

Comment: As there's very little to no link with the colonization, it's very (too?) close to a pure astronomy/physics question, ie. off-topic here. Perhaps explicitly tell the link between colonization and the need for Earth gravity?

Comment: If the moon were an artificial construct with a shell over some interior space with some super-dense core (eg. a kind of [shellworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellworld)) then gravity near the core could be much higher than at the surface. Real-world seismic experiments have shown that our moon is unlikely to be such a structure, but if you were prepared to have the history of your setting be a little different, it is an option and one that could be even be hard(ish) scifi, if you wanted.

Answer (score 9):

**No**

However, unlike other answers are suggesting, your question does have merit.

Gravity would indeed be strongest at the surface of a spherical body with uniform density. However, neither Earth nor Moon have uniform density.

[image: Earth gravity]

Earth has a large and dense iron core, so if one stands on top of it, free fall acceleration there is higher than that on Earth surface. However, gravity there is only marginally higher than the surface gravity. For Moon, situation is even less fortuitous. Moon's core is relatively small, so it is unlikely that gravity gradient inside the Moon ever exceeds its surface gravity. Reaching Earth's level of gravity is out of question.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

Gravity is controlled by mass and distance, according to Newton.

Since the mass of the mass of the Moon is less than that of Earth and also its density is lower, there is no way you can have a gravity similar to Earth anywhere in the Moon.

The only possibility would it be for it to be way more dense, so that you could have much more mass in a smaller radius. But that's not the case.

To put it in numbers, you want the gravity acceleration at a distance $R^*$ from the whole mass of the Moon be the same as on Earth surface. This means

$GM_E/R_E^2=GM_M/(R^*)^2$ which turns into $(R^*)^2=R_E^2M_M/M_E$.

Considering that $R_E=$6371 km, $M_M/M_E=$0.01 you would get that you would need to concentrate the entire mass of the Moon into a sphere of radius about 8 km to get the same surface gravity as on Earth.